# Difference between "I am doing lunch" and "I am having lunch"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

What is the difference between *I am doing lunch* and *I am having lunch*? Both indicate progress of action.

Comment: To me, "to do lunch" seems to have a connotation of eating lunch *with a secondary purpose in mind* - "do lunch with a colleague/client" or "do lunch with a friend" - as if "lunch" was on your to-do list, for some reason, and you wanted to cross it off. "To have lunch" sounds quite neutral to me, on the other hand. If a friend said "we should do lunch" to me, it sounds like a future invitation to eat *together*; if a friend said "we should have lunch", it sounds as though it's reached lunchtime and we should both eat, and doesn't imply "together". But other people may think differently.

Comment: I would rarely use the phrase *I am doing lunch* by itself. You don't "do" lunch by yourself or with yourself: We could "do lunch" or I could "do lunch" with a friend. I think the only way I would use the solitary phrase *I am doing lunch* would be in the sense of *I am preparing lunch* (for someone/some group/us, etc.)

Comment: Also, *having* and *doing* may not "indicate progress of action" -- they may be statements of intention. "I'm having lunch with Joe tomorrow". —Welcome to ELU.

Comment: @Robusto  I don't think this is a duplicate. Some of the answers there mention OP's issue, but the treatment is hardly helpful.

Comment: @StoneyB: That may be. In case you're right, I've answered below with the only meaningful distinction I can think of.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, either. You *can* "do lunch", but it's a different sort of thing than "having lunch".

Comment: "Do lunch" usually indicates an intention to set up a lunch at some time in the future. You wouldn't use this with a family member or a close colleague with whom you often eat. It's sometimes used as a brushoff; i.e., the time for that lunch will never arrive. "Have lunch" is more general, and may be an indication that it's lunch time right now and we should go to the kitchen or restaurant. You can _also_ use it for the first case. More here: http://www.barrypopik.com/index.php/new_york_city/entry/lets_do_lunch/

Comment: The question as it stands has multiple issues. It should be closed until it is edited to show the OP's efforts at research, and until the text in question is expanded to show enough context. Until then, the question is both incomplete and nonconstructive.

As for it being a duplicate, the main objection I've seen is that the existing answers over at the other question are inadequate. That never means we should have duplicate open questions. That means we need a better answer over at the other question.

Comment: When I hear "Let's do lunch", I think of a Hollywood business meeting at a restaurant between 11:30 a.m. and 3:00 p.m. When I hear "Let's have lunch", I think of filling my stomach with food that I hope tastes good. So, for me, at least, "doing lunch" is "doing business and, incidentally, eating & drinking at the same time" while "having lunch" is "eating the midday meal & maybe talking about something interesting other than business". Other folks may have other understandings, though.

Answer (score 6):

All right, here's one difference: You can *have* lunch by yourself or with others, but you generally don't speak of *doing* lunch unless you are doing it with others. "Doing lunch" is slang for meeting someone and having lunch together.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another difference which might plausibly be UK-specific: *doing lunch* can mean *making* lunch. A family may ask themselves, "Whose turn is it to do lunch today?"

A statement "I'm doing lunch" can mean "I'm in the process of making lunch"; whereas "I'm having lunch" would mean "I'm in the process of eating lunch".

This is in addition to the meaning Robusto has alluded to: someone may make a suggestion "Let's do lunch," which usually means "Let's meet for lunch". However even that could mean (for example, on Christmas morning, when a Christmas meal might take several hours to prepare) "Let's start to make lunch".

Unfortunately there is not enough context in the question to determine the meaning required.

Comment: It's not exclusively UK; it's used in the US, too. However, I'd only expect to hear it with the meaning "undertake responsibility for making lunch", so it still has Robusto's group sense - "Who's doing lunch?" "I'm doing lunch for the gang before the game."